# How do I output multiple records for sum()

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following table:

Table1

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | longitude | score |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 |        18 |    10 |
|  2 |        18 |    10 |
|  3 |        19 |     5 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

I'm trying to create a query that selects all the data from the Table1 where longitude = 18 but only outputs the records where the sum of the scores is greater than 15. So essentially, I'm looking for this output:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | longitude | score |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 |        18 |    10 |
|  2 |        18 |    10 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

I've been trying multiple queries but none of them gives me what I'm looking for or they have some syntax errors. I've tried this one:

> select * from Table1 where longitude = 18 having
>   sum(score)>15

but it produces this result:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | longitude | score |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 |        18 |    10 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

How can I format the query in such a way that multiple records are being output instead of just one? I've tried using joins but I had issues with them.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server

Comment: @SeanLange mysql

Comment: @SeanLange xamp server- mariadb / mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY`:

```
select longitude, sum(score) score_sum
from Table1 
where longitude = 18 
group by longitude
having sum(score)>15
```

You can check it out [here](http://rextester.com/PXI71827).

Comment: it returned an empty result set

Comment: glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum with windowing function as below:

```
select * from (
select id, longitude, score, Sm = sum(score) over(partition by longitude) from #yourTable ) a
where a.sm > 15 and a.longitude = 18
```

Comment: MySQL does not support window functions till version 8 at least.